# Delaying a task in C# - db context disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, garbage-collection

I have a situation where I need certain code to execute at a certain time (in my ASP .NET Core project).

I know that delaying a task is not a great solution, but this is what I have and I'd like to know how to make it work:

```
async Task MyMethod()
{
  // do something
  // Create a new thread that waits for the appropriate time
      TimeSpan time = dbAppointment.ScheduledOn - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5.0) - DateTime.UtcNow;
      _ = Task.Delay(time).ContinueWith(async x => await 
          notificationManager.CreateReminder());
  // continue doing something
}
```

When I try to run the code, it enters the method that is supposed to be executed, at the right time:

```
public async Task CreateReminder() {}
```

but fails when it tries to use my `dbContext` which I injected using DI into the `NotificationManager` constructor, stating that it was disposed.

This is the "flow" of the dependencies:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly MyContext dbContext;
  private readonly INotificationManager notificationManager;
  public MyClass(MyContext context, INotificationManager nm) 
  { 
    dbContext = context;
    notificationManager = nm;
  }

  public async Task MyMethod() // the method shown in the snippet above
  { 
    // method does something using the dbContext

    _ = Task.Delay(time).ContinueWith(async x => await 
          notificationManager.CreateReminder());
  }
}

public class NotificationManager: INotificationManager
{
  private readonly MyContext dbContext;
  public NotificationManager(MyContext context) { dbContext = context;}
  public async Task CreateReminder() { // this method uses the dbContext}
}
```

DI setup in startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(); 
services.AddScoped<INotificationManager, NotificationManager>();
```

Comment: As for "why": https://stackoverflow.com/q/40844151/11683

Comment: Just curious: why not `await Task.Delay(time); await notificationManager.CreateReminder();` ?

Comment: Can you please add the relevant DI setup?

Comment: @Fildor In *startup.cs*: 

`services.AddDbContext<MyContext>();
services.AddScoped<INotificationManager, NotificationManager>();`

Comment: I added that into your question. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Eutherpy I'm facing the same issue. Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: @Arman I ended up using the Hangfire library, it's really simple to use and does everything I need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options

- Use a job scheduler (Like [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire), [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), [Jobbr](https://github.com/jobbrIO), ...)
- Use a [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) if your .net core version is >= 2

In both cases you'll need to inject the DatabaseContext in the job class otherwise you'll receive an ObjectDisposedException.

When you need to scale-out to multiple machines you'll need a job server with a state store like SQL Server, MSMQ, RabbitMQ, Redis,...

Sample with Hangfire

```
public class MyDelayJob
{
   private readonly MyContext dbContext;
   private readonly INotificationManager notificationManager;
   public MyDelayJob(MyContext context, INotificationManager nm)
   {
       dbContext= context;
       notificationManager = nm;
   }

   public async Task Run(/*parameters*/)
   {
      await notificationManager.CreateReminder()
   }
}

/*Shedule code in MyMethod
    IBackgroundJobClient can be injected
    you need to register MyDelayJob with your IOC container.
 */

backgroundJobClient.Schedule<MyDelayJob>(j => j.Run(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
```

See the docs for [IBackgroundJobClient](https://api.hangfire.io/html/T_Hangfire_IBackgroundJobClient.htm)